# Beacon - StartRanging and stopRanging depend on the Beacon Proximity

Tags: ios, ibeacon, use-case, estimote

Can somebody help me how to solve the issue.

My current beacon setup :

Beacon device - Estimote.
UUID - same for the two beacons.

1. I have placed each beacon in two rooms, rooms are 20-30 Meters away from each other
2. I'm hitting webservice and updating something (when the proximity is near or immediate)  when i enter a specific room (checking if major and minor of this room actually belongs to this room)
   3.It  also hits another webservice and updating something (when the proximity is far and unknown).

Problem with the current algorithm:
1. When i enter room 1 and if it is near or immediate, it hits webservice1. When this happens, room2 proximity will be far or unknown, then again webservice2 is hitting and also there are lot of fluctuation. Sometimes when i'm in room1, room2 beacon proximity shows as near. I don't this to happen

New Approach and Questions

1. I would like to Monitor for specific region , say room1 when i'm near say 5 meters away, and start ranging the beacon only when proximity is near or immediate. and stop ranging when proximity is far or unknown or i'm more than 5 meters away
2. When i move near to room2 (5 meters away) and if the proximity of room2 is near or immediate, it should start ranging room2 and stop ranging room1
3. I would like to have clear approach or way to write algorithm to achieve the above. Calculation can be using the proximity or using some other idea (like combination of RSSI and proximity or something else)

It would be great if you can explain me in detail with example on how to achieve the new approach or you can tell me if there is any other better approach, but please explain with code.

My foremost concern is, it should't range room 2 beacon when i'm in room1 or just 5 meter away from room1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about putting each beacon in its own region? So room 1 would be a region, and room 2 would be another region.

After that I would make use of `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and `locationManager:didExitRegion:`. Within these, you can start and stop the ranging of your two beacon regions depending on which room you are in.

Please note, the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html/) state that:

> When testing your region monitoring code in iOS Simulator or on a device, realize that region events may not happen immediately after a region boundary is crossed. To prevent spurious notifications, iOS doesn’t deliver region notifications until certain threshold conditions are met. Specifically, the user’s location must cross the region boundary, move away from the boundary by a minimum distance, and remain at that minimum distance for at least 20 seconds before the notifications are reported.
>
> The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and
>   the location technologies that are currently available. For example,
>   if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less
>   accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the
>   minimum distance is approximately 200 meters.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (region.identifier == YOUR ROOM 1 IDENTIFIER)
    {
       //Start ranging room 1
    }
    else
    {
       //Start ranging room 2
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (region.identifier == YOUR ROOM 1 IDENTIFIER)
    {
         //Stop ranging room 1
    }
    else
    {
         //Stop ranging room 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried using the identifier property. I'll try and let you know. As I said my earlier, two rooms are close (about 20-30 away from each other). Do you feel it will be perfectly ok if I use identifier without determining the proximity or some other range determining factor ?

Comment: @user3310076 Yep, the proximity won't matter. When you stop ranging for room 1 and start ranging for room 2 for example, the device will only be looking for beacons in room 2, the room 1 beacons will be disregarded until you start the ranging for them.

Comment: I'm almost there. I tried with the identifier, when i walk towards room 1, it starts ranging for the beacons in the room 1, when i leave room 1 and walk towards room 2 , it starts ranging for the beacons in the room 2. But the problem is, when i come back towards room 1 from room 2, it is not identifying the region. Since it is not identifying the region, it is not ranging the beacons.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the enter and exit region methods, since both the rooms are just 20-30 meters away, enter region is called for both the rooms when i go near by room 1 or room 2 and exit region is called for both the rooms when i move > 50 meters from room 1 or room2. I don't want this to happen. My desired output is, when i'm near to room1 or room2 (say 5m away), then i need to range the beacons for specific region and determine it's proximity/rssi/accuracy/or any better calculation factor , and hit the web service.

Comment: @user3310076 I think what you're trying to achieve is complicated, there is currently no way of determining how close the device is to a specific region. The only thing I have used is the `proximity` property to check if I am immediately over a beacon. Have you set your CLLocationManager's `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`?

Comment: Yes, it did set the desiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest. Proximity factor almost works, but then fluctuation is the causing the issue and it depends on how the beacon is placed/positioned. Anways, thanks for all your time

Comment: @user3310076 No problem, I hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is sending info to the server at inappropriate times.  It really has nothing to do with starting ranging.

You cannot start ranging when proximity is relatively close -- you have to range in order to determine proximity.

Rather than an algorithm that starts and stops ranging, I suggest you simply leave it on all the time, and build a filter that decides when to make the server calls.  Here's a starting point for the logic I would suggest:

Call the server if all the following  are true:

- beacon.accuracy < 3
- all other beacons detected have beacon.accuracy > 3
- no server call has been made for this beacon recently

**EDIT:** You can reduce the fluctuation on the accuracy reading by setting your beacon transmitter power as high as possible to maximize the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Good answer. The reason I suggested to start and stop ranging was because @user3310076's device was saying he was near the beacon in room 2 when intact he wasn't. So if he stops ranging room 2's beacon when in another region, this issue would no longer occur.

Comment: Also, the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/accuracy) say not to use `accuracy` to determine the location of a beacon as the values may fluctuate due to RF interference.

Comment: Yeah I tried with accuracy and proximity, since there is lot of fluctuation,  I wanted better approach.

Comment: When it comes to deciding whether to take action based on detecting bluetooth devices, you basically have three options (1) take action if you see a beacon at all, regardless of signal strength (2) take action if you see a beacon and its signal strength is above a threshold (accuracy, proximity and RSSI are all metrics derived from signal strength) or (3) Logic based on a combination option 2 coming from multiple beacons.  You can't change the laws of physics, so using some variant of the third option, as suggested in the my answer, is really the best you can do.

Comment: I'm trying with the 3rd approach. Accuracy + average of accuracy for certain period :) Thanks for your input so far.